# Change combobox Text property to "Not found" if the saved item is not found in the list wpf mvvm

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, combobox

I have a C# wpf mvvm application and some data is coming from db. I have a combobox and what I want to achieve is: when the data from db is not in the combobox list, in the combobox I want to be writen:"Not found data". If it is possible I want to do this from the xaml.

I have tried :

```
 <Trigger Property="SelectedItem" Value="{x:Null}">
        <Setter Property="Text" Value="No Item Selected"/>
    </Trigger>
```

but it is not working.

Answer (score 1):

the easiest i can think of is to overlay a textblock

```
    <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" MinWidth="100">
        <ComboBox x:Name="myComboBox" ItemsSource={Binding ...}"/>
        </ComboBox>
        <TextBlock Text="No data found" IsHitTestVisible="False" Margin="3">
            <TextBlock.Style>
                <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding SelectedItem, ElementName=myComboBox}" Value="{x:Null}">
                            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </TextBlock.Style>
        </TextBlock>
    </Grid>
```

Control libraries like telerik or devexpress often contain controls with this feature.